# How do you do something after you render the view? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I want to do something after I have rendered the view using

```
return render_to_response()
```

Are signals the only way to do this? Do I need to write a custom signal or does request_finished give me enough information? Basically I need to know what page was rendered, and then do an action in response to that.

Thanks.

UPDATE FROM COMMENTS: I don't want to hold up the rendering of the page, so I want to render the page first and then do the action.

Comment: That seems backward.  You know what page you're about to render.  Just do the action.  Why can't you simply insert the extra action in the view function?  Please provide some hint as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: i dont' want to hold up the rendering of the page, so i want to render the page first and then do the action

Comment: @rick: Please don't comment on your own question, please update your question with additional facts.

Answer (score 12):

You spawn a separate thread and have it do the action.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=do_my_action, args=[my_argument])
# We want the program to wait on this thread before shutting down.
t.setDaemon(False)
t.start()
```

This will cause 'do_my_action(my_argument)' to be executed in a second thread which will keep working even after you send your Django response and terminate the initial thread. For example it could send an email without delaying the response.

Comment: I tried this implementation. Apparently, the second thread launched terminates even if its task is not yet done. In my case, it's updating several DB entries

Answer (score 5):

If you have a long-running process, you have two simple choices.

1. Spawn a subprocess prior to sending the response page.
2. Create a "background service daemon" and pass work requests to it.

This is all outside Django.  You use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) or some other IPC method to communicate with the other process.

Comment: Agreed -- I'd use some kind of IPC to make this modular and web-server neutral. You probably don't want to hack on Django internals to do things after the response is sent.

Answer (score 5):

A common way to do this is to use message queues.  You place a message on the queue, and worker threads (or processes, etc.) consume the queue and do the work after your view has completed.

Google App Engine has the task queue api http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/, amazon has the Simple Queue Service http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/.

A quick search didn't turn up any django pluggables that look like accepted standards.

A quick and dirty way to emulate the functionality is to place the 'message' in a database table, and have a cron job periodically check the table to perform the work.

Comment: +1 An even more efficient idea than (hopefully) lightweight IPC messages.

Answer (score 5):

Django's HttpResponse object accepts an iterator in its constructor:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators

So you could do something like:

```
def myiter():
    yield "my content"
    enqueue_some_task()
    return

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponse(myiter())
```

The normal use of an iterator is to send large data without reading it all into memory.  For example, read chunks from a file and yield appropriately.  I've never used it in this way, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will make the page appear to still be loading on the client-side after it has fully loaded, as the server doesn't close the connection until the final result is yielded.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite solution: A separate process that handles background tasks, typically things like indexing and sending notification mails etc. And then, during the view rendering, you send an event to the event handling system (I don't know if Django has one built in, but you always need one anyway so you should have one) and the even system then puts a message in a message queue (which is trivial to write unless you have multiple machines or multiple background processes) that does the task in question.

Answer (score -1):

In render to response, you pass the html page that you want displayed. That other page needs to send a post (via Javascript or something) that triggers the correct function in your views, then that view calls the correct next page to be shown.

Comment: yeah that would work, but i wonder if there's a way to do it solely on the server side

Comment: i'm not sure that's really possible : /

Comment: that definitely cannot be done server side. The server doesn't know anything about what the client is doing, so it will never know that the page is finished rendering. of course, a simple post will solve that problem.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps I do not understand your question. But why not something simple like:

```
try:
    return render_to_response()
finally:
    do_what_needs_to_be_done()
```

Comment: Once it's returned, the view will be rendered right? Regardless of what is happening in the finally section?

If so, this is just what I need!

Comment: it doesn't seem like it works. the rendering is held up while the code in the finally is running.

Comment: When there's a finally clause the return out of the function only happens _after_ the code in finally is executed, so this won't work as intended.