# Alternative to django-celery to perform asynchronous task in Django?

Tags: django, asynchronous

In my admin I have a form allowing to upload a file to fill the DB.

Parsing and filling the DB take a long time, so I'd like to do it asynchronously.

As recommended by several SO users I tried to install `python-celery`, but I can't manage to do it (I'm on Webfaction).

Is there any simple, easy-to-install alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If webfaction supports cron jobs you can create your own pseudo broker.  You could save your long running tasks to the db and in a 'tasks' table, this would allow you to return a response to the user instantaneously.  Then there could be a cron that goes through very frequently and looks for uncompleteled tasks and processes them.

I believe this is what django mailer does
https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419640/594589

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gearman](http://gearman.org/index.php) along with it's [python client library](http://packages.python.org/gearman/library.html)

It's very easy to setup and run gearman. Try few examples.